# How can I output the shipping-cost value in this code?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm newbie, I want to understand.

Cant output shipping-cost value.

It seems like I'm doing everything right, but I'm not getting the result.

I will be very grateful for your help

Code:

```html
<select class="form-select" name = "shipping" id="country" required>
  <option value="">Choose...</option>
  <option value="DPD">DPD</option>
  <option value="DHL">DHL</option>
  <option value="DHL Express">DHL Express</option>
</select>
</label>

<div class="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  const selectElement = document.querySelector('.form-select');

  selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    const result = document.querySelector('.result');
    result.textContent = `You chose ${event.target.value}`;
  });
</script>

<div class="shipping-cost"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  const shippingCost = document.querySelector('.text-success');
  const shippingCostDisplay = document.querySelector('.shipping-cost');

  selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    const result = document.querySelector('.result');
    result.textContent = `You chose ${event.target.value}`;
    switch(event.target.value) {
    case 'DPD':
      shippingCost.textContent = '$5';
      break;
    case 'DHL':
      shippingCost.textContent = '$10';
      break;
    case 'DHL Express':
      shippingCost.textContent = '$15';
      break;
    default:
      shippingCost.textContent = '$0';
    }
    shippingCostDisplay.innerHTML = shippingCost.textContent;
  });

</script>
```

It seems like the line `<div class="shipping-cost"></div>` should be responsible for this, but, unfortunately, it does not perform any function

Comment: The code snippet in the question is producing an error.  Have you noticed that error on your browser's development console?

Comment: Where is the element with the class `text-success`?

Comment: Yes, but it to difficult to understand for me what exactly is causing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `<div class="text-success"></div>`.

M.Eriksson is correct with his question in the comment.

**Why?**

Because you are missing `div` with class `text-success`, but you are trying to set it's value in `switch`, hence javascript throughs an error (mentioned by David)

**Here is a working example** (refactored just a bit your code)

```js
const selectElement = document.querySelector('.form-select');
const shippingCost = document.querySelector('.text-success');
const shippingCostDisplay = document.querySelector('.shipping-cost');

  selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    const result = document.querySelector('.result');
    result.textContent = `You chose ${event.target.value}`;
    switch(event.target.value) {
    case 'DPD':
      shippingCost.textContent = '$5';
      break;
    case 'DHL':
      shippingCost.textContent = '$10';
      break;
    case 'DHL Express':
      shippingCost.textContent = '$15';
      break;
    default:
      shippingCost.textContent = '$0';
    }
    shippingCostDisplay.innerHTML = shippingCost.textContent;
  });
```

```html
<form>
<select class="form-select" name = "shipping" id="country" required>
  <option value="">Choose...</option>
  <option value="DPD">DPD</option>
  <option value="DHL">DHL</option>
  <option value="DHL Express">DHL Express</option>
</select>
</form>

<div class="result"></div>

<div class="shipping-cost"></div>

<div class="text-success"></div>
```

**I would refactor your task like this:**

```js
const selectElement = document.querySelector('.form-select');
const shippingCost = document.querySelector('.text-success');
const shippingCostDisplay = document.querySelector('.shipping-cost');

  selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    const result = document.querySelector('.result');
    result.textContent = `You chose ${event.target.value}`;
    shippingCostDisplay.textContent = shippingCost.textContent = event.target.value;
  });
```

```html
<form>
<select class="form-select" name = "shipping" id="country" required>
  <option value="$0">Choose...</option>
  <option value="$5">DPD</option>
  <option value="$10">DHL</option>
  <option value="$15">DHL Express</option>
</select>
</form>

<div class="result"></div>

<div class="shipping-cost"></div>

<div class="text-success"></div>
```